# How find function $h(x)$ such have Infinite time differentiable

Tags: analysis

let $f(x),g(x)\in C^{\infty}(-\infty,+\infty)$ are give two functions,and such
$$f^{(n)}(1)=g^{(1)}(1),f^{(n)}(-1)=g^{(n)}(-1),n\in N$$

How  find  a function $h(x)$, and $h(x)$ is differentiable infinitely often on $(-\infty,+\infty)$,such
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x)&x\in(-1,1)\\
g(x)&x\in(-\infty,-1]\bigcup[1,+\infty)
\end{cases}$$
can you take example $h(x)$?

This problem I have consider sometimes,and I can't find this $h(x)$ such this condtions,can you help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: What can you do if $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)\neq g(1)$?

Answer (score 0):

Unless $f(1)=g(1)$ and $f(-1)=g(-1)$ this $h$ is not even continuous. For infinite differentiability we additionally need to require that $g^{(n)}(1)=f^{(n)}(1)$ and $g^{(n)}(-1)=f^{(n)}(-1)$ for all $n$. On the other hand, given these conditons $h$ is automativcally $C^\infty$.

Comment: sorr,I have edit,Thank you